# Determination of special values of Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

We have the Eisenstein series of weight $k$: $G_k(z)=\frac 1 2 \sum_{m,n} \frac 1 {(mz+n)^k}$. Can we evaluate it in closed form for some special values of $z$, eg. $z=i$ or $z=\omega$?
It is clear by symmetry that $G_k(i)=0$ unless $k$ is a multiple of 4, but is there a closed form for $G_4(i)$, for example?
The problem is very similar to determining the values of the $\zeta$ function at even integers, so I guess that the Weierstrass elliptic function could be of use here (it is the “equivalent” of the cotangent function for lattices in $\mathbb C$, as $\sum_n \frac 1 {x+n} = \pi \cot (\pi z)$

Comment: Perhaps this is not going in a direction of interest to you, but...: suitable linear combinations at CM/Heegner points gives special values of Hecke L-functions. Suitable of these special values were investigated by Dammerell and by Shimura c. 1970s, and in terms of Deligne's conjectures on special values, are "knowable" in a certain finite range (of your "k"), with a common (presumed) transcendental (in addition to $\pi$) consisting of a Petersson inner product of the associated modular form. Is this of interest?

Comment: These: $1+240\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{3}e^{-2\pi n}}{1-e^{-2\pi n}}=\frac{3\pi^{2}}{4\Gamma(3/4)^{8}}$,
$1+240\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{3}e^{-4\pi n}}{1-e^{-4\pi n}}=\frac{33\pi^{2}}{64\Gamma(3/4)^{8}}$,
$1+480\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{7}e^{-2\pi n}}{1-e^{-2\pi n}}=\frac{9\pi^{4}}{16\Gamma(3/4)^{16}}$ were produced by looking at special values of Jacobian theta functions. I only hazily remember how I arrived at them.

Answer (score 19):

It is well known that $$G_{4k}(i)=\left(4\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx\right)^{4k}\frac{H_{4k}}{(4k)!}, $$ where $H_{4k}$ are called Hurwitz numbers. $H_4=\frac{1}{10}$ and $H_{8}=\frac{3}{10}$ are the first two such numbers, but in general these come as coefficients in the Laurent series of Weierstrass's elliptic function. The introduction of Tsumura's paper *On certain analogues of Eisenstein series and their evaluation formulas of Hurwitz type* gives more details, and the relevant paper by Hurwitz is cited there.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming there's no known closed form for that integral?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, let $t= x^4$ you obtain $$\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^{-1/2}dx=\frac14\int_0^1 (1-t)^{-1/2} t^{-3/4} dt= \beta(1/2,1/4) =\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}=\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1/4)^2\frac{\sin(\pi/4)}{\pi}$$
also the LHS is an elliptic integral which comes from integrating $\frac{dx}{y} =dz$ on a basis of the homology of $y^2=x^3+x \overset{\wp}\cong \Bbb{C/r(Z+iZ)}$ and relating it with $\Delta(i)$ then extending to all $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ modular forms using they are all in $\Bbb{C}[E_4,E_6]$

Comment: @reuns There is a factor of four missing in the denominator of the last expression (the final expression should be $\Gamma(1/4)^2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8\sqrt{\pi}}$).

Comment: Is there a similar expression for other values of $z$? I would guess that $z=\omega$ could be another “nice” value.

Comment: There is nothing special about $i$ (or $\omega$) here; in principle you can do this for any $z$-value of the form $a + b \sqrt{-D}$ with $b^2 D > 0$, but the explicit formulae will get messy quite fast. The role of the Hurwitz numbers will be played by special values of Dirichlet L-series.

Comment: Another simple formula holds for $G_6(\omega_1,\omega_2)=120 \sum\limits_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{1}{(m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^6}$. When $\omega_1=2\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^6}} dx$, $\omega_2=i\omega_1(-1/2+\sqrt{3}/2i)$, $G_6=4$. There are more formulas for imaginary quadratics $\tau=\omega_2/\omega_1$ in Katayama's paper "On the Values of Eisenstein Series".

Comment: The same observation of @reuns applies to writing the second integral in terms of Beta/Gamma function values.

Answer (score 5):

For real Eisenstein series
$$ \sum_{(m,n)\ne(0,0)}\frac{1}{|m\tau+n|^s}, $$
the Kronecker limit formula gives the value  at $s=1$ in terms of the Dedekind eta function.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_limit_formula
For CM values of $\tau$, one gets a product of $\Gamma$ values.

Answer (score 3):

- $$\wp(z) = \frac1{z^2}+\sum_{(n,m)\ne (0,0)} \frac1{(z+ni+m)^2}-\frac1{(ni+m)^2}$$
  is the unique even $\Bbb{Z}+i\Bbb{Z}$ periodic meromorphic function with only one double pole at $0$ where $\wp(z) =  \frac1{z^2}+O( z^2)$. We obtain $\wp(z)=\frac1{z^2}+3 G_4(i)z^2 + 5 G_6(i)+O(z^6)$ where $G_6(i)=0$ so that $$\wp'(z)^2=  4 \wp(z)^3-60G_4(i) \wp(z)+O(z^2)$$ The $O(z^2)$ term vanishes because it is analytic doubly periodic with a zero at $0$.

  $\wp(\frac{1-i}2)= -\wp(\frac{1+i}2)=0$
- $$\frac{1+i}2=\int_0^{\frac{1+i}2} dz = \int_0^{\frac{1+i}2} \frac{d\wp(z)}{\wp'(z)}=\int_0^{\frac{1+i}2} \frac{d\wp(z)}
  {\sqrt{4\wp(z)^3-60G_4(i)\wp(z)}}$$ $$=\int_\infty^0 \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x^3-15 G_4(i) x}}
  =\frac{i}{2}( 15 G_4(i))^{-1/4}\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty \frac{dX}{\sqrt{X-X^3}}$$ 
  $$=\frac{i+1}{2}(15G_4(i))^{-1/4} \int_0^1 \frac{dt^{1/2}}{\sqrt{t^{1/2}(1-t)}}=
  \frac{i+1}{4}( 15G_4(i))^{-1/4}\beta(1/4,1/2)$$ $$=\frac{i+1}{4}( 15 G_4(i))^{-1/4}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/4)} =\frac{i+1}{4}( 15G_4(i))^{-1/4}\Gamma(1/4)^2 \sqrt{\pi}  \frac{\sin(\pi/4)}{\pi}$$

  and hence $$G_4(i)=  (\frac{1}{2}15^{-1/4}\Gamma(1/4)^2 (2\pi)^{-1/2})^4$$
- If $k$ is odd $G_{2k}(i)=0$. To find $G_{4k}(i)$  we'll need to show that the first cusp form for the full modular group is $\Delta(z) = (2\pi)^{-12}e^{2i\pi z} \prod_{n \ge 1} (1-e^{2i \pi nz})^{24} $ of weight $12$ , since it has only one simple zero at $i\infty$ then $\frac{E_4(z)^3-E_6(z)^2}{\Delta(z)}$ is a modular form of weight $0$ thus it is constant,  thus for $f$ of weight $2k=4a+6b\ge 12$  then $\frac{f-f(i\infty) E_4(z)^a E_6(z)^b}{\Delta(z)}$ is of weight $2k-12$ and by induction $f$ is a polynomial in $E_4,E_6$.

  Whence $$E_{4k}(z) = \sum_{4a+6b=4k} c_{a,b} E_4(z)^aE_6(z)^b, \qquad G_{4k}(i)= c_{k,0} 2 \zeta(4k) E_4(i)^k=c_{k,0} 2 \zeta(4k)\frac{G_4(i)^k}{(2\zeta(4))^k}$$
  where the $c_{a,b} \in  \Bbb{Q}$ are found from the first few coefficients of the $q$-expansion of $E_{4k},E_4,E_6$.

Comment: Your formula for $G_4(i)$ is off by a factor of $\frac1 2$ compared to the literature. That is probably because you define $G_k$ as $\sum \frac 1 {(mz+n)^k}$, whereas I defined it as $\frac 1 2 \sum \frac 1 {(mz+n)^k}$. Also, the limits on the second and third integrals should be $0$ and $\infty$, not the corresponding values of $z$.

Comment: The standard definition is $G_k(z)=\sum_{(m,n) \ne (0,0)} \frac{1}{(mz+n)^k},E_k(z)= \frac{G_k(z)}{G_k(i\infty)}$, and they are riemann stieltjes integrals over $z$

Answer (score 1):

Im writing a paper about negative weights Eisenstein series evaluated at $z=i$. Set
$$
E_{\nu}(z)=1+\frac{1}{\zeta(1-\nu)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{\nu-1}(n)q^n\textrm{, }q=e(z)\textrm{, }Im(z)>0.
$$
I have evaluated among other values ($C$ is Catalan constant):
$$
E_{-2}(i)=\frac{7\pi^3}{\zeta(3)}\textrm{, }E_{-2}'(i)=\frac{i(240C\pi-29\pi^3)}{720 \zeta(3)}\textrm{, }E_{-2}''(i)=\frac{80C\pi-11\pi^3}{240 \zeta(3)}
$$
$$
E_{-2}^{(3)}(i)=\frac{i\left(1-E_{4}(i)\right)\pi^3}{15\zeta(3)}\textrm{, }E_{-2}^{(4)}(i)=\frac{2E_{4}(i)\pi^3}{15\zeta(3)}
$$
$$
E_{-4}^{(5)}(i)=\frac{8i\pi^5}{63\zeta(5)}
$$
In general holds the trivial formula
$$
E_{2n+2}(z)=1+\frac{\zeta(2n+1)}{\zeta(-2n-1)(2\pi i)^{2n+1}}\frac{d^{2n+1}}{dz^{2n+1}}E_{-2n}(z)
$$
Also
$$
E'_{-4}(i)=-2iE_{-4}(i)+\frac{13i\pi^5}{1890\zeta(5)}
$$
$$
E_{-4}''(i)=-3E_{-4}(i)+\frac{11\pi^5}{378\zeta(5)}-\frac{\pi^2\zeta(3)}{4\zeta(5)}
$$
$$
E_{-4}^{(3)}(i)=3iE_{-4}(i)-\frac{i\pi^5}{14\zeta(5)}+\frac{3i\pi^2\zeta(3)}{2\zeta(5)}
$$